# File IO operations in .NET throws IO Exception

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a code written in VB.NET which comprises of two File Operations namely **File.Exists()** and **File.Delete(filepath)**, where filepath is the path of the file to be deleted. Whenever, I run this code, the first time it executes with no issues, as in:-

If **File.Exists** is true then **File.Delete**, however, the issue occurs the next time I try to perform the same operations for another file. Saying 'the File is being used by some process'. Here, the only thing I did was use File.Exists and File.Delete operations. No reading file/stream or copying/creating files or opening/closing files.

Can anyone enlighten me on the topic and provide me with some suggestions?

Also, I have tried most suggestions from stack overflow, but to no avail.

**Edit:-** **(Code used)**

```
Dim dir As String = "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/" 
Dim filePath As String = "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/'somefile'"
Dim fileInfo As New FileInfo(filePath)


Try

    If Directory.Exists(dir) Then

       If File.Exists(filePath) Then

          File.Delete(filePath)

       End If

Catch ex As Exception

   Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message)

End Try
```

Comment: Are you calling the second Exists and Delete immediately after the first calls?

Comment: Yes, checking if file exists and then deleting, if it does. But not after first call, I have a button calling the function comprising of the two file operations.

Comment: Is the path the same (same file) on each Delete call? Depending on the file system, file deletes take time. If you pause does it run successfully?

Comment: (I know people hate this suggestion, but just try it for a second) Try putting `Application.DoEvents` on the line before `File.Exists`.  It will force a thread synch and sometimes catches-up a pending background operation (like file.close, flush, etc)

Comment: It would be much easier for members to help you if you posted your code.

Comment: Best suggestion - post your code

Comment: There is no point in using File.Exists, deleting a file that isn't there is just fine.  If any *other* process is also accessing the file and used the FileShare.Delete option then the file does not disappear immediately.  Not until that other process is done with it.  And File.Exists will fail, the file is in a "delete pending" state.  A common example of the kind of process that does this is an anti-malware product.  The kind of virus that often infects a programmer's machine when it sees an executable file appear from no-where.

Comment: Added the code which I am having problems with, please do check.

Answer (score 0):

I could not recreate this.

Test

```
Private Shared prng As New Random
Private Sub Abuse()
    For x As Integer = 1 To 50
        FileTest()
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine("done")
End Sub

Private Sub FileTest()
    Dim b(2047 * 1024) As Byte
    prng.NextBytes(b)

    'setup a test folder
    Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    Dim testF As String = IO.Path.Combine(path, "testƒ")
    If Not IO.Directory.Exists(testF) Then
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(testF)
    End If

    'create some files
    Dim fn() As String = {"one", "two", "three"}
    For Each f As String In fn
        Dim p As String = IO.Path.Combine(testF, f)
        p = IO.Path.ChangeExtension(p, "txt")
        Dim fs As IO.FileStream = IO.File.Create(p)
        fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length) 'write some data
        fs.Close()
        fs.Dispose()
    Next

    fn = IO.Directory.GetFiles(testF) 'retrieve files just created
    For Each f As String In fn
        If IO.File.Exists(f) Then
            IO.File.Delete(f)
        End If
        If IO.File.Exists(f) Then 'shouldn't exists
            IO.File.Delete(f)
        End If
    Next

    If IO.Directory.Exists(testF) Then
        IO.Directory.Delete(testF, True)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't what I'm looking for. I did mention that I am not using any Open/Write file operation, so there's no way could do a File Close/Dispose.